# How to write interface for a nested list?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I am trying to write an interface for a matrix in Typescript,
I unable to find a way to describe the type `Array<Array<number>>` as interface.

```
    const matrix:Array<Array<number>> = [
        [0,0,0],
        [1,1,1],
        [0,1,0],
    ]
```

Instead  I want something like

```
//dosen't work
    interface Imatrix {
    [index:number]:Array<number>
     }
```

which can then be used in a function that works with Imatrix

```
function draw(matrix:Imatrix){
     matrix.forEach(()=>{
     //some code
      })
 }
draw(matrix)
```

when I do this I get error Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Imatrix'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use an interface, you can do it like this:

```js
interface Row<T> extends T[]
{
  [cell: number]: T
}

interface Matrix<T> extends Row<T>[]
{
  [cell: number]: Row<T>
}
```

(Maybe you'd like to know that `T[]` is synonymous with `Array<T>`.)

But TypeScript uses structural matching, so there is no difference between a *type* and an *interface*, they are just different syntax for the same thing. That's, for example, why we don't use the `I` prefix in front of interface names. The code that I've written above is identical to this:

```js
type Row<T> = T[];
type Matrix<T> = Array<T[]>;
```

---

If you want to add your own methods to `Matrix`, the correct OOP way would be to make a class for it which contains the nested array as an property:

```js
type Row = number[];

class Matrix
{
  elements: Array<Row>;

  multiply(B: Matrix)
  {
    /* do something with elements */
  }
}
```